# Вывести на экран несколько элементов связного списка

Tags: java, list, список

Пытаюсь разобраться в связных списках. Есть класс Node в котором прописаны методы, и есть класс List в котором с помощью этих методов добавляются элементы списка. Не могу понять как правильно добавлять больше одного элемента а потом вывести их на консоль.
Пример кода был взят с 
[Связный список](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)

```
private int data;

private Node next;

public int getData()
{
    return this.data;
}

public void setData(int data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

public void setNext(Node next)
{
    this.next = next;
}
public Node getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Node nin  = new Node();
    nin.setData(2);
    System.out.print(nin.getData());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Node head  = new Node();
head.setData(2);

Node next = new Node();
next.setData(3);
head.setNext(next);

// Выводим элементы списка в консоль.
Node current = head;
while (current != null) {
   System.out.println(current.getData());
   current = current.getNext();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все стало понятно.